# Insert data from form field to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Since being new to .NET i am having difficiltues in connecting my VS 2013 with SQL.

I have already connected it with the DB but now i want to know how can i insert data in my AdventureWork Databaze, from a text box that is in my page. Can you please help me cuz really im not getting it
Below you can find some of my code:

```
<h1>Add in Database</h1>
    <div>
    Enter Name:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
   </br></br>
</div>
    Enter Surname:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </br></br>
    Gender:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC3300" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </br></br>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server">
        ConnectionString="<$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString >"
         SelectCommand="INSERT INTO [users] VALUE ([FirstName] = @FirstName)" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    <br />

    <br />
        </form>
```

and: `

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert  into users (FirstName,LastName,Gender) Values (@Name,@Surname,@Gender)",cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox5.Text);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();

        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get some exception?

Comment: Should your SelectCommand really be INSERT INTO [users] VALUE ([FirstName] = @FirstName) ?

Comment: Please explain what is the problem. (a part from _not get it_)

Comment: i want to insert data in my SQL datbase, and this data will come from a form(textbox) that the user will insert. the problem is that im not finding how to achive this

Comment: @Paul alan. Maybe not. i was trying different forms

Comment: Notice that your ASPX markup calls a server side 'event handler' named _Button1_Click_ but the code that tries to insert is in the _Button2_Click_

Comment: Put a break point into Button2_click to see if it works.

Comment: the break point leads to errors :/

Answer (score 0):

While I am unsure why the code above is not working.  I have duplicated this and rewritten the button click handler code.  Here is my working sample below:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
        cnn.Open();

        var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into users (FirstName,LastName,Gender) Values (@Name,@Surname,@Gender)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", TextBox5.Text);

        var affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //  Do validation here.
        //  This should be 1, the number of rows inserted.
    }

    if (IsPostBack)
        TextBox3.Text = TextBox4.Text = TextBox5.Text = string.Empty;       
}
```

I noticed that in your sample you are attempting to open the database connection twice.  Other corrections you could make would be to wrap your SqlConnection in a using statement.  In that way when the object disposes, it will close the connection for you.  Also check the resulting number of rows affected coming back from the insert statement.  This may give you some clue as to why the data is not inserted.  If you are using SQL Server Developer Edition, you can start the SQL Profiler to see the resulting T-SQL statement being sent from your application to the SQL Server.  I hope this helps.

Comment: i am trying this and leads me to this errror:                                          
    Error 11 The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context C:\...............\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DB\DB\UserReg.aspx.cs 30 27 DB

Comment: Do you have a using statement at the top of your file? `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BusinessEntityID', table 'AdventureWorks2014.dbo.users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: If you do not have default constraints on the database, you must fill in all of the required data.  This is the schema validation that is reporting this error.  On the upside at least you know that you are attempting to insert data now.